# How to compare elements of nested lists between each other?

Tags: python-2.7, list, string-comparison

I try to compare elements of nested list between each other. Let's say I have the following list:

```
list1 = [['v1', '1', '2'],['v1', '2', '2'], ['v2', '1'], ['v3'], ['v4', '1'], ['v4', '2']]
```

and I would like to reach to:

```
result = [['v1', '2'],['v1', '2'],['v2', '1'], ['v3'], ['v4'], ['v4']]
```

I've done a small code, but it does not look to work very well.

```
for i in range(1, len(list1) - 1):
    previousone = list1[i-1]
    currentone = list1[i]
    nextone = list1[i+1]
    lenprevious = len(previousone)
    lencurrent = len(currentone)
    lennext = len(nextone)
    minlen = min(lenprevious,lencurrent,lennext) -1
    common = ''
    for j in range(minlen):
        if j == 0:
            if previousone[j] == currentone[j]:
                common += str(previousone[j])
            if previousone[j] != currentone[j]:
                if currentone[j] == nextone[j]:
                    common += str(currentone[j])
                else:
                    common += currentone
                    break
        else:
            if common != '':
                if previousone[j] == currentone[j]:
                    common.join('_',str(nextone[j]))
                else:
                    if currentone[j] == nextone[j]:
                        common.join('_',str(nextone[j]))
                    else:
                        break
            else:
                break
    print common
    result.append(common)
```

The idea, is to compare the 1st element of the sub-list vs the 1st element of the previous sub-list. If no match, then we compare with the next sub-list. If no match, we get in `common` the 1st element of the current sub-list.
Then, if it's matching, we do the same for the next element of the sub-list and so one until the last one. In the end, I want to have in `common`, a list of the common elements if any, if not I want the current sub-list.
Does anyone has any idea how to make it work? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT ::
The logic would be:**

`Iteration 1 -> Previous : ['v1', '1', '2'] and Current : ['v1', '2', '2'] and Next : ['v2', '1']`

We compare each element from each list.
First, we compare the Previous and the Current.
First element of those lists are 'v1', so we append 'v1' in result and we go to the next element, here '1' and '2'.
They are not the same so we pass until the next element, which are '2' and '2': identical.
We append in result to get Result :

`[['v1', '2'], ['v1', '2'], [], [], [], []]`

`Iteration 2 -> Previous : ['v1', '2', '2'] and Current : ['v2', '1'] and Next : ['v3']`

First we compare Previous and Current. 'v1' different from 'v2'.
So we compare Current and Next. 'v2' different from 'v3'.
So we append in result the current and we get:

`[['v1', '2'], ['v1', '2'], ['v2', '1'], [], [], []]`

`Iteration 3 -> Previous : ['v2', '1'] and Current : ['v3'] and Next : ['v4', '1']`

Same as above, 'v2' different from 'v3' and 'v3' different from 'v4' so we append the current and get:

`[['v1', '2'], ['v1', '2'], ['v2', '1'], ['v3'], [], []]`

`Iteration 4 -> Previous : ['v3'] and Current : ['v4', '1'] and Next: ['v4', '2']`

'v3' different from 'v4' so we compare Current and Next: 'v4' is common so we append 'v4':

`[['v1', '2'], ['v1', '2'], ['v2', '1'], ['v3'], ['v4'], []]`

`Iteration 5 -> Previous : ['v4', '1'] and Current : ['v4', '2'] and Next : ??`

'v4' is common so we append 'v4' and get the final result:

`Result: [['v1', '2'], ['v1', '2'], ['v2', '1'], ['v3'], ['v4'], ['v4']]`

But I do not know how to reach there..

Comment: I am not able to understand the idea by which you are able to create this  result `result = [['v1', '2'],['v1', '2'],['v2', '1'], ['v3'], ['v4'], ['v4']]`. Could you please provide step by step explanation, that would be very helpful in getting the conditions.

Comment: @ShubhamVaishnav
The idea is to keep only what's common between the sub-lists, only if the first element of the sublist is common. I am not able to create this result, this is what I want to get.
So first I compare the first element of the current sub-list with the previous sublist. If they are the same, then the common part is that element. If it's not the same, then we compare the first element of the current sub-list with the next one.
Then, if the first element is the same, I want to compare the other elements, and get what's common only.

Comment: I wanted a sudo logic of how you are comparing and getting the results, anyways, according to what I have understood, if the first element of the two sub-lists doesn't match then we have the current list as output and if the first element of the two sub-lists match then the output is the common elements between them. Am I right?

Comment: @ShubhamVaishnav yes, you are right.
I am not sure what is a sudo logic, tell me if I can help more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the implementation according to your desired result,

**Core Logic**

```
def intersection(lst1, lst2): 
    return list(set(lst1) & set(lst2)) 


list1 = [['v1', '1', '2'],['v1', '2', '2'], ['v2', '1'], ['v3'], ['v4', '1'], ['v4', '2']]
result = []
list_len = len(list1)

if list_len == 0:
    pass
elif list_len == 1:
    result.append(list1)
else:
    for i in range(list_len):

        if i == 0:
            current = list1[i]
            next = list1[i+1]
            print("Iteration {} -> Previous : No previous available Current : {} Next: {}".format(i, current, next))
            if current[0] == next[0]:
                result.append(intersection(current, next))
            else:
                result.append(current)    

        elif i == list_len - 1:
            previous = list1[i-1]
            current = list1[i]
            print("Iteration {} -> Previous : {} Current : {} Next: No next available".format(i, previous, current))
            if current[0] != previous[0]:
                result.append(current)
            else:
                result.append(intersection(current, previous))

        else:
            previous = list1[i-1]
            current = list1[i]
            next = list1[i+1]
            print("Iteration {} -> Previous : {} Current : {} Next: {}".format(i, previous, current, next))
            if current[0] == previous[0]:
                result.append(intersection(current, previous))
            else:
                if current[0] == next[0]:
                    result.append(intersection(current, next))
                else:
                    result.append(current)



print("Result : {}".format(result))
```

**Output**

```
Iteration 0 -> Previous : No previous available Current : ['v1', '1', '2'] Next: ['v1', '2', '2']
Iteration 1 -> Previous : ['v1', '1', '2'] Current : ['v1', '2', '2'] Next: ['v2', '1']
Iteration 2 -> Previous : ['v1', '2', '2'] Current : ['v2', '1'] Next: ['v3']
Iteration 3 -> Previous : ['v2', '1'] Current : ['v3'] Next: ['v4', '1']
Iteration 4 -> Previous : ['v3'] Current : ['v4', '1'] Next: ['v4', '2']
Iteration 5 -> Previous : ['v4', '1'] Current : ['v4', '2'] Next: No next available
Result : [['v1', '2'], ['v1', '2'], ['v2', '1'], ['v3'], ['v4'], ['v4']]
```

Comment: It's not really giving me the result I want, but I'll try to work around it. Thanks!

Comment: @LoC, That's what I asked you to share, how you are reaching to that result. Because according to my understanding of comparing we should get this result and not the one you desire. Could you please share the step by step comparison of the lists similar to what I have shared in my Output, add the comparision in your question and I will update my code accordingly.

Comment: I've edited my question @Shubham Vaishnav, with the logic, and a bit more explanation, please let me know if this is what you need? Thanks!

Comment: @LoC, Why do we get two lists in output in the 1st iteration and not later in the 5th iteration?

Comment: Because I am not sure how to deal with the first and the last item of the list. I mean, ideally the first current is 'v1', '1', '2'] and we compare it only with the next one as we don't have previous. For the last item, we compare it only with the previous as we don't have next. But I don't know how to deal with it, so I've put it like that. Tell me if this is unclear. Thanks! @Shubham Vaishnav

Comment: @LoC, Good News, I have achieved your desired result. You can have a look.